# Comparison of class name

Tags: r, class

When I check a class name of objects by the code `if (class("x") == "character")` , R CMD check says that

```
Found if() conditions comparing class() to string: if (class("x") == "character") ...
Use inherits() (or maybe is()) instead.
```

However, the suggested functions `inherits` and `is()` do not distinct the class and its inherited class as the following code, in which I made a class `classAAA` and its inhertied class `classBBB` and make an object `sss` of `classBBB` and try to distinct these class by the functions `inherits` or `is()`. But, the both functions have same results.

What I want is a function `foo()` such that `foo(s, "classAAA") = TRUE` and `foo(s, "classBBB") = FALSE`.

```
#Make a class
    setClass("classAAA",
             slots = list(aaa = "numeric") 
    )
    
#Make an inherited class
    setClass("classBBB",
             slots = list(bbb = "character"),
             contains = "classAAA"
    )
 # Make an object
    sss <- new("classBBB", 
             aaa = 21, bbb="India")
    show(sss)
    
 #Check class of sss
    inherits(sss,"classAAA")
    inherits(sss,"classBBB")
    
 #Check class of sss 
    is(sss,"classAAA")
    is(sss,"classBBB")
```

Comment: If you need that, one might question why classBBB contains classAAA. Are you aware that objects can (and frequently do) have more than one class? `if (class("x") == "character")` is always a bug waiting to happen. At least do `if ("character" %in% class("x"))` (`"character"` is a poor example because it usually is not an explicit class).

Comment: For the code you've shared, wouldn't the object ```sss``` return ```true``` for both? For example, if you were to do say ```aaa <- new("classAAA", aaa = 22)``` then ```inherits(aaa,"classBBB")```, you would get ```false```